# cpp simple thread program crashes at exit

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to understand how to work with threads and this simple code crashes with this error:
[image]

the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void thread1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        cout << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
    }
}

void main()
{
    thread t1(thread1);
    thread t2(thread1);

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    t1.detach();
    t2.detach();
}
```

can someone please explain why it crashes after the detaches and how to fix this?

Comment: `std::thread::detach()` usually is a bad idea.

Comment: but i have no choice

Comment: Informally, all (non shared) resouces shoud be reclaimed by the OS when your program exit. But in this case, there are still some runing threads, which makes the OS mad.

Comment: i want to eventually write a multithread server so i have to learn how to use these commands

Comment: so how do i close them?

Comment: You can use a singleton class to manage all those long-runing threads, and inform them and join them on ending of the service.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get an error is accessing CRT (C++ Runtime Library) after its deinitialization.

The worker threads use CRT by accessing `std::cout`. When the main thread leaves `main` function, the CRT library is unloading, but the worker threads are still trying to use it. Likely, there is a runtime check for it so you get a error message instead of just program crash.

It is better not to use `detach` method and be sure that all the threads you spawned are finished execution at program exit.